# LUIS Authoring API: How do I filter LUIS utterances by intent?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I need to retrieve all the labeled utterances (aka examples) for a particular intent.

It appears the only call in the LUIS Authoring API to do this is [GET review labeled examples](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a):

`/luis/api/v2.0/apps/:appId/versions/:versionId/examples?skip=0&take=500
/luis/api/v2.0/apps/:appId/versions/:versionId/examples?skip=500&take=500`

This returns *all* utterances for *all* intents. I have 880 labeled utterances, and due to the verbose reply, it's a 2.5MB file. This makes it slow.

The LUIS web UI uses a filtered call:
`/luis/webapi/v2.0/apps/:appId/versions/0.1/models/:modelId/reviewLabels`. The resulting file is usually 10-50kB. However, there is no documentation around this call (notice the `webapi` in the path rather than just `api`).

So: is there a supported method for retrieving a filtered list of utterances?

Comment: I dont think Microsoft has exposed API for that functionality. Alternatively you can [export](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40) the Model and apply LINQ to filter out utterances based on intent. That is the only way IMHO

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Exporting the model (i.e. `https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/:appId/versions/:versionId/export`) produces a much smaller file, but it doesn't provide any ids. Without ids, it's useless from a programmatic perspective.

Comment: are you talking about version Id's???

Comment: @KunalMukherjee When you call `/examples/`, each example has a unique numeric ID. `/export` doesn't provide that.

Comment: you can get all the `/examples` in batches of 500 from this [Programmatic API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Yes. The point of this question is that retrieving all examples is 2.5MB. I only need examples for 1 intent, which would be a 10kB file if it was possible. Loading 2.5MB for no reason takes too long and wastes resources.

Comment: Exactly but Microsoft should expose an API for doing that right?

Answer (score 4):

> is there a supported method for retrieving a filtered list of utterances?

AFAIK, I could't find an API for this from server side, after research I found that even the Luis Web UI doesn't use any filter provided by server, it just gets all the utterances from server side and create filter use js in the foreground.

Since you're stratified with the result using `webapi` for Luis Web UI, after testing, we can call this `webapi` exactly the same as calling `api` together with `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` as head, for example we can code like this in C#:

```
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{SubscriptionKey}");
        var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/webapi/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionNumber}/models/{modelId}/reviewLabels";
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        //TODO:
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

There's no official document about this `webapi`, but we can try to use `Postman` to analyse the http requests.

Comment: The `/reviewLabels` URI does not provide entity information. `entityLabels` is sent as an empty array. Therefore it's not a complete replacement to `/examples`, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath, this `webapi` is the only method I can find for this purpose till now, I can't say it's reliable since there's no official support for this. And I used some built-in intents in Luis service and a self-defined "greetings" intent for testing, the `entityLabels` returns the correct response to me.